# How can I extract all the parameters from an SQL-like line?

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite, visual-c++

How can I extract all the parameters from an SQL-like line, in C++?

```
CREATE TABLE students ((id, integer, 1000), (name, text, 128), (group, text,50))
```

I want to have all this information stored in different variables, to get them like:

```
command_name="CREATE TABLE"
table_name="students"
column1_name="id"
column1_type="integer"
column1_value="100"
```

And so on and so forth for the rest of the columns.
I think it will be easier if they are stored in arrays though.
I tried to do it in a lot of ways, but I can't seem to find an appropriate one, all of the work I did was manual and it requires a lot of code and I want something faster.

Comment: You basically need to make our find a SQL parser.

Comment: Yes but is there any other way, rather than doing it manually? I cannot think about how can I implement all I did in a function, or faster. Is just an endless nested if, i don't think it is practical.

Comment: Without a full SQL parser, another way would be using multiple regex calls to identify specific parts of the query. Of course, you will have to do some concessions in name of simplicity. But should be fairly simple to write regex to cover your basic needs.

Comment: and that sql statement is not  valid

Comment: Have a look at [PRAGMA table_info()](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_table_info).

Comment: I know the statement it's not valid, I try to make my own SQL engine from scratch that doesn't really work like the orginal one.